# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/user"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

SingularI have this problem. I defined in route file my route:

```
namespace :admin do
    root to: "home#index"
    resources :define_user
end
```

I created users controller:

```
class DefineUsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
   ...
  end

  def destroy
  ...
  end
  end
```

I created in views new folder 'define_users' with file 'show.html.haml'. I call it using link_to:

```
=link_to 'User', admin_define_user_path
```

And I get above error. I would like to stay with **singular** name. Thank for all answers.

Comment: Try giving like this `=link_to 'User', admin_define_user_path(@define_user)`

Comment: And do you have a `show` method in the controller?

Comment: With show method don't work and without too.

Comment: I didn't get what you said.

Comment: I tried with show method and It didn't work. I tried also without show method and It didn't work;)

Comment: How Rails will know what DefineUser model you want to see? You must provide an id! Why you want to escape it?

Comment: @user2239655 why you want `show` method without `id`? Do you want something like profile page? don't use show method, because that's default method with `:id`. You can use other method/add a method as `profile` or else. On `routes.rb` looks like this `"define_user/profile" => "define_users#profile"`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access show route without id of DefineUser object

```
= link_to 'User', admin_define_user_path(define_user)
```

Where define_user is an object of DefineUser class or id of this object

Comment: I edited my question is It possible to do this without any id. With singular path?

Comment: @user2239655, Nope. You can only hardcode id, but it must be present.
Or, as an option you can define custom route to show, but it\s really weird)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to link_to some define_user, you have to provide object or id. Something like this: `admin_define_user_path(@define_user)`.
To display all possible routes type `rake routes` in console.

Also resources should be in plural form.

Moreover you have to provide namespace in controller.

P.S.
As I see, it is a very bad idea to work with model called `DefineUser`. It's not a rails way. Just use `User`. `DefineUser` is a good name for method, but not model.

So, the best idea to handle your code:

routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
  root to: "home#index"
  resources :users
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ...
  end
end
```

view

```
= link_to 'Users', admin_users_path # for index
= link_to 'User', admin_user_path(@user) # for one user
```

Good idea to separate controllers by namespace. For example, you can have next structure:

```
application_controller.rb
admin #folder
 L base_controller.rb
 L users_controller.rb
 L ..._controller.rb
```

So your base_controller should be inherited from application_controller

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin_layout' # Different layout for all admin pages
```

Other controller in admin namespace will be inherited from base_controller

```
class Admin::UsersController < Admin::BaseController
  def create
    ...
  end
```

Comment: Yes you re right It work for me but I have specific situaltion. I write user name I and I get user data. I would like to have singular routes. It will be more clean

Comment: I have not understood what you need =) 
You can do resource: define_user in routes. You can't link to some object without providing its id.